# Установка различных изображений для элементов списка DropDown Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть проблема добавления изображений для элементов Dropdown. При указании изображений для Options в Inspector эффект отсутствует. Пытаюсь добавлять Options в коде:

```
public class FillDroPDown : MonoBehavior
{
  public Dropdown dd;

  void Start ()
  {
     dd.options.Clear();
     dd.AddOptions(new List<Dropdown.OptionData>
     {
        new Dropdown.OptionData
        {
           text="1", 
           image=Resources.Load("LeftToRight.png", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite
        }
     });
  }

void Update () {

  }
}
```

Текстовые данные успешно отображаются, а изображения - нет. Просьба помочь с решением данной проблемы. Версия Unity 5.3.4f1.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно что бы ресурсы(в даном случае спрайт) были именно в папке Resources. Я сам промучился с этим т.к. нигде этого не находил очень долго.
Если же у тебя оно в дочерней категории папки Resources (например Resources/Sprites)-- должен писать

```
image=Resources.Load("Sprites/LeftToRight.png", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite
```

---

А вообще, советую тебе дропдаун создать вручную, поменять все что нужно и дальше генерить его с префаба. А не писать под это дела скрипт. Или как минимум, подогнать вид самого дропдауна с префаба, а текст уже задавать скриптом.